# OpenCV244 Visual Studio 2012 CV_8U undefined

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 with OpenCV 2.4.3 for some time and everything worked just fine

I now upgreaded Visual Studio 2010 to 2012.

When i Use the code i written in VS2010 which worked perfectly fine in 2012 i get this error:

[image]

There is no other issues with any functions that I use everything seems to work good its just for these two instances that i get an error.

Any solutions....?

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but you've done a "clean solution" on the project before rebuilding, no? We've come across several gremlins in VS2012 that are almost leading us to roll back to VS2010, so there's no telling what you may have found :)

Comment: There is no guarantee that code compiled with compiler A will work well together with code compiled with B, even if they are just versions of the same compiler. A full recompile (libraries and all) is the safest bet.